Poor performance in ListPlot[] Mathematica 14
Recently I started working with Mathematica 14 and I notice a new dynamical feature in the functions Plot[] and ListPlot[],
Namely, when I roll my mouse over a data point a little window shows up indicating its coordinates automatically

My problem is that I need to make plots with tens of thousands of points, and this feature (I think!) significantly slows down my code to the point where the Kernel simply crashes down. Note, I didn't have this problem with earlier versions.
I tried to disable the Dynamical updating in the Evaluation menu which does allow me to generate my plots, but as a result an ugly gray rectangle shows up right at the center, which covers a whole lot of data and is also present when I export the figure to pdf.

I would really like to disable this feature somehow, while maintaining other features of dynamical updating.

Please see Notebook starts formatting content automatically and then collapses.

This works for me
  ListPlot[Prime[Range[25]], PlotHighlighting -> None]

No gray box and no Highlighting  when moving the mouse over the points.

V 14
